# Best way to take an input from a list?

Tags: java, android

I'm relatively new in the world of android, and I'm trying to make an application to manage some business trips.
Each trip is made to a city, i was wandering, what is the best way to write down the city? Right now i have an edit text where the user can write the city, there must be some better way, any hints?

Comment: You could use a `AutoCompleteTextView` or `Spinner`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make EditText and "+" button next to it. Typed city can go to the list after taping "+". You can use RecyclerView for list for example. You can see this in adding bookmarks in Podcast Go app.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to map that city to an existing one, it is a better idea to use something that is more controlled and not free as an EditText.

`Spinner` or a `Popup` with list selection could be a good option for that. To make sure that the user chooses a valid city.